# How to put one word in parenthesis with sed and a regex?

Tags: regex, sed

I would like to put one word in parenthesis with sed and a regex but I don't know how to do it.

I think the command shoud look a little bit like this :

```
sed -r "s/???/\(&\)/g"
```

but I don't know know how to match a word without whitespaces...

If I try on this example :

```
WORD
abc = WORD
```

I get :

```
(WORD)
(abc = WORD)
```

What I want is :

```
(WORD)
abc = (WORD)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found what I was looking for :

```
sed -r "s/WORD/\(&\)/g"
```

It was quite simple actually.

Comment: The output of this command is quite different than what the expected output was requested to be.

Comment: I edited the answer so it's perfectly correct now

Answer (score 0):

Using `sed`, you can match capitalized characters

```
$ sed 's/[[:upper:]]\+/(&)/' input_file
(WORD)
abc = (WORD)
```

or the last alphabetic characters at the end of the line

```
$ sed 's/[[:alpha:]]\+$/(&)/' input_file
(WORD)
abc = (WORD)
```